# Defining a parameterized method for tasks in C#

Tags: c#, locking, race-condition, multitasking

I'm programming in C#. I want to run 3 methods using 'Task'. I write my codes as below:

```
    public void ExtractLicensePlate()
    {
        var tasks = new Task<List<RotatedRect>>[3];

        tasks[0] =
            new Task<List<RotatedRect>>(ExtractLicensePlateUsingSimpleCanny);

        tasks[1] =
            new Task<List<RotatedRect>>(ExtractLicensePlateUsingMorphology);

        tasks[2] =
            new Task<List<RotatedRect>>(ExtractLicensePlateUsingSobel);

        for (var i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
            tasks[i].Start();

        ExtractedRotatedRectangles =
            tasks[0].Result
            .Concat(tasks[1].Result)
            .Concat(tasks[2].Result).ToList();
    }
```

It seems that these codes run correctly. In `ExtractLicensePlateUsingSimpleCanny` and `ExtractLicensePlateUsingMorphology` two lines of codes are the repeated as written below:

```
    private List<RotatedRect> ExtractLicensePlateUsingSimpleCanny()
    {
        UMat edgeImage = new UMat();
        CvInvoke.Canny(Input, edgeImage, CannyThreshold, CannyLinking);

        //some codes...
    }

    private List<RotatedRect> ExtractLicensePlateUsingMorphology()
    {
        UMat edgeImage = new UMat();
        CvInvoke.Canny(Input, edgeImage, CannyThreshold, CannyLinking);

        //some codes...
    }
```

I want to change two functions as below to calculate `edgeImage` once, So I use a parameter for each method:

```
    private List<RotatedRect> ExtractLicensePlateUsingSimpleCanny(UMat edgeImage)
    {   
        //some codes...
    }

    private List<RotatedRect> ExtractLicensePlateUsingMorphology(UMat edgeImage)
    {
        //some codes...
    }
```

Now when I use them in my code as below, I see unexpected results:

```
    public void ExtractLicensePlate()
    {
        var edgeImage = new UMat();
        CvInvoke.Canny(Input, edgeImage, CannyThreshold, CannyLinking);

        var tasks = new Task<List<RotatedRect>>[3];

        tasks[0] =
            new Task<List<RotatedRect>>(() => ExtractLicensePlateUsingSimpleCanny(edgeImage));

        tasks[1] =
            new Task<List<RotatedRect>>(() => ExtractLicensePlateUsingMorphology(edgeImage));

        tasks[2] =
            new Task<List<RotatedRect>>(ExtractLicensePlateUsingSobel);

        for (var i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
            tasks[i].Start();

        ExtractedRotatedRectangles =
            tasks[0].Result
            .Concat(tasks[1].Result)
            .Concat(tasks[2].Result).ToList();
    }
```

How can I fix it?
It should be noted that, I also use `.Clone()` for `edgeImage` and `Task.WaitAll(tasks)` but I still see unexpected results. I'm new to `Task`, It seems that it is a `race condition` but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: FWIW you shouldn't be using the Task constructor (use `Task.Run` or similar) or using `Result` (can result in deadlocks, use await/async instead). Unlikely to fix your issue but worth a shot

Comment: As @BradleyDotNET said, there's no point in manually starting tasks.  You could just use Task.WaitAll or Task.WhenAll (with ConfigureAwait) to run them in parallel.  You haven't explained what is going wrong but my first guess would be that edgeImage contains some mutable state that is being changed by the two tasks in parallel.